# sepic converter using lm3478

Tags: dc-dc-converter, sepic

Is it possible to  make a sepic converter **of 120 W** using [LM3478](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3478.pdf) ?
I am trying to make  the circuit in TI web bench but it is not supporting over 12V 3A in LM3478.

Comment: You should provide more information. What is the input voltage range?

Comment: input voltage - 10 to 15V and output voltage 12V

Comment: SEPIC converters are recommended for around 50W. Above it is recommended to use Buck-boost topology:
https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2017/05/31/how-to-approach-a-power-supply-design-part-2